# Opacity issues with Cocos2d iPhone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, opacity, cocos2d-iphone-3

I'm having issues with opacity on several animations in Spine after an upgrade to Cocos2D 3.1.1 from Cocos2D 2.1

To better ilustrate what I am talking about, here are two videos that show the difference between the animations:

YouTube Video: [Cocos2D 2.1 (See "explosion animation" around 6 seconds into the video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Io_qXab2mtw)

YouTube Video: [Cocos2D 3.1.1 (See "explosion animation" around 7 seconds into the video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fXptGQAFyK0)

I have already tried the following:

- Having my designer export the Spine Animation on both non-premultiplied and premultiplied alpha values.
- Tried setting the blendMode programmatically (via [SkeletonAnimation setBlendMode] ) to either one of:

  - [CCBlendMode alphaMode]
  - [CCBlendMode premultipliedAlphaMode]
  - [CCBlendMode addMode]
  - [CCBlendMode multiplyMode].

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: can you take two screenshot and put them next to each other? the videos aren't too helpful, plus there are severe block artifacts in them (I recommend taking videos from device using airplay and an airplay server tool, ie reflector or I think even Quicktime is capable of being an airplay mirror receiver).

Comment: Hi Stephen! I'm right now at work here in the US.  I'll be taking those screenshots after work hours, ASAP.  Thanks!